# Is it good idea to control program flow based on message from Exception?

Tags: java, sockets, serversocket

For example I have a TCP server:

```
ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(12345)
boolean doAccept = true;
while (doAccept) {
    try {
        serverSocket.accept();
    } catch (SocketException e) {
        if (serverSocket.isClosed()) {
            LOGGER.info("Server stopped.", e);
            doAccept = false;
        } else if (e.getMessage().equals("Too many open files")) {
            LOGGER.warn("Unable to accept. Will retry in 5 seconds.", e);
            Thread.sleep(5_000);
        } else {
            LOGGER.error("Socket error.", e);
            doAccept = false;
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        LOGGER.error("I/O error.", e);
        doAccept = false;
    }
}
```

If `ServerSocket::accept` throws a `SocketException: Too many open files`, I would like only to log the exception but keep running my TCP server thread and retry accept after a few sec sleep. But in any other cases server thread must be done.

Can I use here safely the message from exception and make sure exception message is always same on every implementation? Or exists any better way to detect that?

**SOLUTION**

Thank you guys for great answers. Only `SocketException` and not any subclasses can be catched in my example. Neither ServerSocket nor SocketException have any `getStatusCode()` method. So I choosed the following simplified solution for my example finally:

```
ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(12345)
boolean doAccept = true;
while (doAccept) {
    try {
        serverSocket.accept();
    } catch (SocketException e) {
        if (serverSocket.isClosed()) {
            LOGGER.info("Server stopped.", e);
            doAccept = false;
        } else {
            LOGGER.warn("Unable to accept. Will retry in 5 seconds.",                 LOGGER.error("Socket error.", e);
            Thread.sleep(5_000);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        LOGGER.error("I/O error.", e);
        doAccept = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's a bad idea to do it based on the *message*, unless you absolutely have to: catching specific subclasses, or doing it on some sort of `getStatusCode()` (which returns an int or enum) etc, is better.

Comment: Addendum: always be careful about using *enums* when the information flows between different systems. Enums that get (serialized using the default java mechanism) are subject to *version* conflicts. And the last thing you need are exceptions during de-serialization because the sender pushed a *new* unknown enum constant to you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, this is definitely an **anti** pattern. Exception *messages* should be seen as human readable information, and **nothing** else. They are **not** meant to be programmatically evaluated. Period. ( and yes, there are systems that actually do programmatically look into messages - but that is more of a "meta" analysis, looking for "patterns", not doing hard "string equals" checking )

Thing is: these exceptions aren't under your control. Meaning: you won't notice when their implementation changes. It is not very likely, but still possible that the exact content/layout of these messages **changes** at some point in the future. And then your whole code falls apart.

In other words: if you need *distinct* error handling, then your code should be throwing *distinct* different kinds of exceptions.

And for the record: I am not saying that there are *easy* solutions just around the corner. But the one you choose, is as said, more of an anti pattern.

Comment: from *messages* I would agree, but from Exceptions in general is *very* debatable, especially if you disable stack-traces for them. Not saying this is incorrect in any form, just augmenting

Answer (score 0):

I would agree with GhostCat 100%, the error message depends on underlaying implementation and should only be used for logging.

Maybe you could find a solution to decide what to do in exception case, if you handle the exception cause:

Take a look at the documentation: [SocketException#getCause](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#getCause--)

Maybe you could find an "too many files"-exception which occurs previously in the stack trace.

Comment: `SocketException::getCause` returns `null` in this case and not any  subclasses can be catched. But I found a simplified solution finally.